# Binary Search: why it won't stop when I return the result

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-search

I can't understand why the function will not stop and return the mid, but it keeps going down to the return -1.

```
public class BinarySearch {

    public static int BS(int[] arr, int target, int first, int last) {
        if(first != last) {
            int mid = first + (last - first)/2;
            System.out.println("arr[mid] = "+arr[mid]);
            if(arr[mid] != target) {
                if(target < arr[mid]) {
                    last = mid - 1;
                    System.out.println("last is "+last);
                    BS(arr, target, first, last);
                }else {
                    first = mid + 1;
                    BS(arr, target, first, last);
                }
            }else {
                System.out.println("Found!");
                return mid;
            }
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    
        if(arr[first] == target) return first;
        System.out.println("Not found!");
        return -1;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test = {0,1,2,4,6,7,9,10};
        int result = BS(test, 7, 0, test.length-1);
        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

Comment: Look at the trace output generated: `Found!
test` - `test` should only be printed when not found, but the value was reported found?!. The main problem is that when you decide a recursive call should complete the work, you don't return it's result: `return BS(arr, target, first, last);`. (Minor: `first != last` isn't "defensive".)

Comment: @greybeard Thanks,Grey. Yes, you are right, I just realise that I have to return the BS . BTW, what 's the meaning of the minor tips? I am curious about it.

Comment: In every call, either `first` is increased, or `last` decreased. What if … `first` got *larger* than `last`? Does the code include a proof they will be equal? Bonus: When you use *crossed* to return *not found*, you don't need to handle value equality in two places.

Comment: Sorry, still confused. I understand the situation you mentioned, but I don't understand why first will be greater than last, cuz each time either of them will +1 only, they have to meet each other ( first == last).

Comment: *Defensive programming is […] to avoid problematic issues **before they arise***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have `return mid` 3 calls deep it is 2nd `BS` that gets that value and since it does not use the value it is lost. Instead it continues to the 3 last lines of the function since that is what the code tells it to do. Unless the element to be found is the first element you never return it.

Recursive functions are not treated special. Their argument, local variables and state are different is not shared and a `return` only returns that one call and does not affect the other ongoing calls.

You could replace each recursive call with a similar function `BS1` that calls `BS2` etc. that produces the same code at each level and it will work the same. Then there will be no recursive call, but it will work the same way. A `return` in `BS4` will not affect `BS3` except for its returned value it should use. One `return` in `BS3` does not cancel the calls `BS2`, `BS1` as they are waiting for an answer to continue their flow. With a `return BS2(arr, target, first, last);` that continued flow is to return the value that the call to `BS2` returns.

Your first calls that returns is `System.out.println`. If it worked that the first `return` was the final result then its value would be the result of your logic.